# Sending mail using external SMTP server uses IP not defined in Azure Web Apps' Outgoing IPs

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, smtp, smtpclient

I have an Azure Web App. When I'm attempting to send an email using my external SMTP server, the source IP from Azure is not one of the ones listed in the Web App's "Outgoing IPs". I need to reliably know what the source IPs may be so I can whitelist it on my SMTP server. Does anyone know why this may be?

If it helps, here's some test code.

```
    private void SendTestEmail()
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(RECIPIENT_EMAIL);
        mail.Subject = "TEST subject";
        mail.Body = "This is a test<BR><BR><BR>";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@mydomain.com", "Testing");
        mail.Body += "<div class=eventBody>This is a test</div><BR><BR>";

        client.Send(mail);
    }
```

The SMTP server address is defined in the web.config and works from known IPs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="mysmtpservernamegoeshere" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: just curious ..where are you setting the smtp.host and smtp port, does this code work when you run it locally..? can you show your web.config file setting..?

Comment: Have you considered storing the host server in the config file e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 I have a sample that does this via a class to read the config file but felt it prudent not to place it as answer in the event this is not what you might need.

Comment: @MethodMan yes, I'm setting the smtp host in the web.config file. I edited my question to include it. The code works when it's from a whitelisted IP. The issue here is that Azure is sending from an IP that's not listed in the Web App's "Outgoing IPs"

Answer (score 0):

When you set up a SMTP client, I am assuming you know the smtp domain, all you have to do is a reverse lookup on that. For example if my smtp host is smtp.office365.com and I do a reverse ip lookup it will give me the ip address of 132.245.229.178, but you should be able to just forward the port for the smtp in your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it wasn't there back when this question was asked, but it might help someone now:

In the Azure portal go to you App Service and open the Resource Explorer.
You will see some JSON data about your App service. One property is the one you want to take a look at: **possibleOutboundIpAddresses**

This is a comma separated list of IP addresses that are possible values for the outgoing IP of your app service. If you add that list to your SMTP server, you should be save.